# How to disconnect from RabbitMQ properly using Perl's AnyEvent::RabbitMQ?

Tags: perl, rabbitmq, message-queue, anyevent

I want to disconnect from RabbitMQ in a proper way. By [reviewing the source code](https://metacpan.org/source/DLAMBLEY/AnyEvent-RabbitMQ-1.19/lib/AnyEvent/RabbitMQ.pm#L439) of Perl's [AnyEvent::RabbitMQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::RabbitMQ) (which I am using), I found the `close` method which seems to close all the channels opened to RabbitMQ.

So I

1. connected to RabbitMQ
2. opened a channel
3. declared an exchange
4. bound to that exchange
5. declared a queue
6. bound to that queue
7. execute the `close` method on the `AnyEvent::RabbitMQ` instance (not the `::Channel` instance)

The connection seems to be closed but the RabbitMQ logs shows that the "AMQP connection" was "connection_closed_abruptly".

Here is the complete RabbitMQ log for that connection:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Jan-2016::10:02:15 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.10868.0> (127.0.0.1:57764 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 14-Jan-2016::10:02:16 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.10868.0> (127.0.0.1:57764 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

Here is the sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strictures 1;

use AnyEvent::RabbitMQ;
use Data::Printer;

my ( $rabbitmq, $rabbitmq_channel );

my $condvar = AnyEvent->condvar;

$rabbitmq = AnyEvent::RabbitMQ->new->load_xml_spec()->connect(
  host       => '127.0.0.1',
  port       => 5672,
  user       => 'guest',
  pass       => 'guest',
  vhost      => '/',
  timeout    => 1,
  tls        => 0,
  tune       => { heartbeat => 1 },
  on_success => sub {
    ($rabbitmq) = @_;
    $rabbitmq->open_channel(
      on_success => sub {
        ($rabbitmq_channel) = @_;
        $rabbitmq_channel->confirm;
        $rabbitmq_channel->declare_exchange(
          exchange   => 'test_exchange',
          type       => 'fanout',
          on_success => sub {
            $rabbitmq_channel->bind_exchange(
              source      => 'test_exchange',
              destination => 'test_exchange',
              routing_key => '',
              on_success  => sub {
                $rabbitmq_channel->declare_queue(
                  queue      => 'test_queue',
                  on_success => sub {
                    $rabbitmq_channel->bind_queue(
                      queue       => 'test_queue',
                      exchange    => 'test_exchange',
                      routing_key => '',
                      on_success  => sub {
                        $rabbitmq->close;
                        undef $rabbitmq;
                      },
                      on_failure => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
                    );
                  },
                  on_failure => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
                );
              },
              on_failure => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
            );
          },
          on_failure => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
        );
      },
      on_failure => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
      on_return  => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
      on_close   => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
    );
  },
  on_failure      => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
  on_read_failure => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
  on_return       => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
  on_close        => sub { $condvar->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
);

my $reason = [ $condvar->recv ];
p $reason;
```

How to disconnect from RabbitMQ properly using Perl's `AnyEvent::RabbitMQ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indicators of reference cycles. These could keep the structure from being properly destructed.

1. "`my $rabbitmq; $rabbitmq = ...`" yells out the possibility of a reference cycle.
2. "`my $rabbitmq_channel; $rabbitmq_channel = ...`" yells out the possibility of a reference cycle.
3. `$rabbitmq_channel` is owned by (stored in) `$rabbitmq`, but it's also captured by `$rabbitmq_channel`'s event handlers.

The changes marked `<===` replace unacceptable code.

The change marked `<---` might be necessary. If `$rabbitmq_channel` is undefined in the callbacks, remove this change.

```
use Scalar::Util qw( weaken );

my $done_cv = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $rabbitmq = AnyEvent::RabbitMQ->new->load_xml_spec()->connect(  # <===
  host       => '127.0.0.1',
  port       => 5672,
  user       => 'guest',
  pass       => 'guest',
  vhost      => '/',
  timeout    => 1,
  tls        => 0,
  tune       => { heartbeat => 1 },
  on_success => sub {
    my ($rabbitmq) = @_;  # <===
    $rabbitmq->open_channel(
      on_success => sub {
        my ($rabbitmq_channel) = @_;  # <===
        {  # <---
          my $rabbitmq_channel = weaken($rabbitmq_channel);  # <---
          $rabbitmq_channel->confirm;
          $rabbitmq_channel->declare_exchange(
            exchange   => 'test_exchange',
            type       => 'fanout',
            on_success => sub {
              $rabbitmq_channel->bind_exchange(
                source      => 'test_exchange',
                destination => 'test_exchange',
                routing_key => '',
                on_success  => sub {
                  $rabbitmq_channel->declare_queue(
                    queue      => 'test_queue',
                    on_success => sub {
                      $rabbitmq_channel->bind_queue(
                        queue       => 'test_queue',
                        exchange    => 'test_exchange',
                        routing_key => '',
                        on_success  => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },  # <===
                        on_failure => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
                      );
                    },
                    on_failure => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
                  );
                },
                on_failure => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
              );
            },
            on_failure => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
          );
        }  # <---
      },
      on_failure => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
      on_return  => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
      on_close   => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
    );
  },
  on_failure      => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
  on_read_failure => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
  on_return       => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
  on_close        => sub { $done_cv->send( __LINE__, @_ ) },
);

my $reason = [ $done_cv->recv ];
p $reason;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a bug in the AnyEvent::RabbitMQ.pm library itself.  I'm uncertain of exactly how to fix the `sub close` itself but the key part is that it never executes the code that sends the `Connection::Close` and `Connection::CloseOk` methods to your RabbitMQ server during global deconstruction.  You can confirm by doing the following after you set up your AMQP connection.

```
$rabbitmq->_push_write(Net::AMQP::Protocol::Connection::Close->new());
$rabbitmq->_push_write(Net::AMQP::Protocol::Connection::CloseOk->new());
```

It's a bit of a hack so I'm working on the proper way to do it and hopefully the maintainer will accept a pull request.